# How to get a single cookie by name from response.Cookies() in Golang?

Tags: string, go, cookies, response, net-http

**Is there a way how to get only one cookie by name from response.Cookies()?**

Let's say that I need the **wr_entry_path** cookie from this cookie jar down below.
`[wr_entry_path=/aP3Mk1i6M/xcp0g1/vMg/Qpr7ccN0OE3p/YxU3A31SAw/RWoGdE/k2DyQ; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Apr 2022 19:40:03 GMT waitingroom=1650392103~id=072e61d9e7fa58639a6a2af28cea89de; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None]`

**Any help appreciated!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Response.Cookies()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.Cookies) returns you a slice of all parsed [`http.Cookie`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Cookie)s. Simply use a loop to iterate over it and find the one that has the name you're looking for:

```
cookies := resp.Cookies()
for _, c := range cookies {
    if c.Name == "wr_entry_path" {
        // Found! Use it!
        fmt.Println(c.Value) // The cookie's value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How should I return the desired cookie? Should I return something like c.Value or? (PS: I'm very new to golang...)

Comment: What should I replace the "Found! Use it!" with to stere the desired cookie as a variable?

Comment: `c.Value` is the cookie's value as a `string`. If you need all other properties of the cookie, return `c`. If just the value, return `c.Value`.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: 
`Cookies := resp.Cookies()
 for _, c := range Cookies {
  if c.Name == "wr_entry_path" {
   Cookie := c.Value
  }
 }
 return Cookie`
but it doesn't work ...

Comment: It should simply be `if c.Name == "wr_entry_path" { return c.Value }`. If you're not familiar with the language basics, please take the [Go tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1) first (else you're gonna have constant problems).

Comment: It should be like this, but when I do it like this I get "missing return at end of function"

Comment: Yes, because if the cookie is not found, the `return` statement inside the `if` would not be reached, but the function still has to return something. That's why you need to use a `return` at the end of your function. Again, please take the Go tour if you're not familiar with language basics.